# How to fix this basic scoping issue

Tags: python, scope

I'm returning a variable in my function and trying to print it in global (as a scoping test), but it's not working. I need the variables in another function but it keeps not recognizing it, whatever I do. Why doesn't the last print in this code work?

```
def assignchar():
    assigning = True
    player2 = ""
    while assigning:
        player1 = input("Player 1: Do you want to be X or O? ")
        if player1.upper() == 'X':
            player1 = 'X'
            player2 = 'O'
            assigning = False
        elif player1.upper() == 'O':
            player1 = 'O'
            player2 = 'X'
            assigning = False
        else:
            print('Please select X or O.')
    print(f'Player 1 is {player1}') 
    print(f'Player 2 is {player2}\n')
    return(player1, player2)
assignchar()
print(player1 + "and " + player2)
```

Comment: you can do this `player1, player2 = assignchar()` `print(player1 + "and " + player2)`

Comment: Define "not working"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to print the returned value, I am adding this answer

```
player1, player2 = assignchar()
print(player1 + "and " + player2)
```